# How do I add single quotes into my awk command output?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, escaping

I’m using Mac Yosemite, bash shell. I want to output single quotes in my output, and I have tried several things, without success …

```
awk -F, '{OFS=",";print ''$1'',$4,$6,$7}' my_list.csv
```

and

```
awk -F, '{OFS=",";print "'"$1"'",$4,$6,$7}' my_list.csv
```

Neither of these adds the single quotes into my output.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can start to help you, otherwise we're just guessing...

Answer (score 4):

using variable is one way to go:

```
kent$ echo "a b c"|awk -v q="'" '$1=q$1q'
'a' b c
```

or you pick the escaping way:

```
kent$ echo "a b c"|awk '$1="'\''"$1"'\''"'
'a' b c
```

I prefer the 1st one.

Comment: The `variable` method is neater and less error prone ++

Answer (score 2):

You can use octal code as well:

```
# octal code 047 for '
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print "\047" $1 "\047", $4, $6, $7}' my_list.csv
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the escape on this statement -- awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1, u.id, u.first_Name, u.last_name, u.url FROM user u, user_role ur where u.id = ur.user_id and lower(ur.role_id) = "\x27"$4"\x27",$4,$6,$7}' my_list.csv  but got the error "awk: syntax error at source line 1".

Comment: What output do you get when you run `awk '{ print "\047" $0 "\047" }' <<< "123"` ?

Comment: Mike - what do you think `u.id` means to awk? Whatever it is - no, it doesn't mean that, hence the syntax error. Not sure what you wanted the code in your comment to do but that is not awk syntax.

Comment: Ah that's right, now I remember why hex code should be avoided.